# phpMyAdmin - can’t connect - invalid setings - ever since I added a root password - locked out

Tags: mysql, root, password-recovery

I run XAMPP,
a few days back i had set up a password for the root password through phpmyadmin
I am not able to access phpMyAdmin ever since that moment

I followed help on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498343/putting-a-password-to-a-user-in-phpmyadmin-in-wamp) but everything seems fine there (in config.inc.php). I even tried unistalling xampp fully, restarting windows and then reinstalling xampp, but still pointing to localhost/phpmyadmin I get the following error

```
MySQL said: 
Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the
connection. You should check the host, username and password in your
configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given
by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I Also tried to reset root password through mysqld.bat as given on mysql's website help but to no avail

Please Help!

Comment: What does a telnet on localhost:3306 output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the config.inc.php file. You can find it in "C:\xampp\phpmyadmin\" and change ~line 21:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']  = 'yourPassHere';
```

Save, and access phpmyadmin again. This will avoid you from having to change the password as stated by Maxwell.

Answer (score 2):

in my case the problem had been solved with changing '127.0.0.1' to 'localhost' !!

```
/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

to >>>

```
/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

good job

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the Mysql password trought the cli by running it with the *--skip-grant-tables* option, next you'll be able to log in with the root user without a password and issue

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Next, restart MySQL normally.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a fix.

Go to this directory `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php` and change the following values to whatever is appropriate for you.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password'; // which is default setting in xampp server
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix. go to `config.inc.php` find the following line of code:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123456';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

If allow no password is `true` make it `false`. If the password is empty, input the password value which you had changed earlier from the phpmyadmin dashboard before you had the error message.